# inserir server_id na criação de cada registro, mysql

Tags: mysql

Eu tenho uma tabela em `mysql` cujos registros podem ser criados de diferentes servidores, esses servidores são configurados como master e slave, e o id de cada servidor foi definido como `1`, `2`, `3` e etç. Eu gostaria de saber se é possível definir o valor padrão de uma coluna para pegar o `server_id` do servidor que está inserindo o registro, algo automático tipo o auto incremento.

**Eu tentei:**

```
ALTER TABLE `mytable` 
ADD COLUMN `somecolumn` TINYINT NULL DEFAULT server_id
```

Mas não funciona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE `minhaTabela` 
ADD `coluna` TINYINT NULL DEFAULT server_id
```

Tenta sem usar `ADD COLUMN` e usa apenas `ADD`